# Retrieving Object from Firebase (AngularFire)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I try to get an object from Firebase with AngularFire and use firebaseObject. However, it did not return an object as I expected. Here is my code

[image]

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('moiveapp', ['ngRoute'],['firebase'])


.factory("Movie", ["$firebaseObject", function($firebaseObject) {
    return function(ID) {
        // create a reference to the database node where we will store our data
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("allmovies").push();
        var movieRef = ref.child(ID);

        // return it as a synchronized object
        return $firebaseObject(movieRef);
    }
  }
  ])
.controller("MovieCtrl", ['$scope','Movie', function($scope,Movie) {
      $scope.test = Movie("001");
  }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this way and it worked.

```
.factory("Movie", ["$firebaseObject", function($firebaseObject) {
    return function(ID) {
        // create a reference to the database node where we will store our data

        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        var movieRef = ref.child('allmovies').child(ID);

        // return it as a synchronized object
        return $firebaseObject(movieRef);
    }
}
])
```